# Qt Application launching but not responding

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qmainwindow

I finished migrating an application from Qt4 to Qt5, it compiles and runs but as soon as the main window is opened I cant do anything (interact with items, or click or anything). its just not responding. I tried debugging it but in the main.cpp reaches the return a.exec(); statement and trying to debug further than that is not posible, the yellow arrow wont go anywhere past that, and if I insist too much it eventually disappears. The functionality of the program is supposed to be alright, I only migrated it. 
What can be causing of this problem? I would post some code but there are so many .cpps and I have so little clue about the issue that I dont know what to post.

I know its not much information, but if anyone has had this problem or knows something related to these symptoms please just say it, it will be better than nothing.
If I missed anything please tell me 
Thankyou.

**Some more info**
Platform: Windows 7 x64
Compiler: MinGW 4.8 32bits
Application: 32bits
I did compile all the libraries and the app in debug mode (except some such as Qxt, which is compiled with the command line and zlib and Qt5SerialPort which includes the debug version itself)

Comment: Try disabling all child widgets in your main window and then turn them on one at a time till you find which one is causing the blocking.

Comment: @RobbieE Is there a specific way to disable a child widget?

Comment: Yes ... comment the code out.

Comment: @RobbieE That was actually very helpful, I dont know how I didnt think of that before omg, I am closer to the error, if I can fix it maybe you could answer the question in case it can help anyone

Comment: @RobbieE I managed to solve it, you may post the answer

Comment: I do deserve the downvotes, I dont know what I was thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling all child widgets in your main window and then turn them on one at a time till you find which one is causing the blocking.